# While setting up windows 7 VM as jenkins slave, facing difficulty

Tags: jenkins

While launching Agent using the launch method *Let jenkins control this Windows slave as Windows service*, I am getting below error:

```
[2019-02-18 17:18:03] [windows-slaves] Connecting to XX.yy.zz.aa
Checking if Java exists
java -version returned 1.8.0.
[2019-02-18 17:18:12] [windows-slaves] Copying jenkins-slave.xml
[2019-02-18 17:18:12] [windows-slaves] Copying slave.jar
[2019-02-18 17:18:12] [windows-slaves] Starting the service
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching an agent. This is probably a bug in Jenkins
org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Service Logon Failure
    at org.jvnet.hudson.wmi.Win32Service$Implementation.start(Win32Service.java:149)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor560.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.kohsuke.jinterop.JInteropInvocationHandler.invoke(JInteropInvocationHandler.java:140)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.launch(ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java:342)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:285)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could someone help me on how to proceed further?

Regards,
Balakrishna K

Answer (score 0):

Service Logon Failure. Can you try after providing credential to the jenkins service in the Windows Service section

Comment: Windows service section you mean "Run Service as: Log on using different account". I have used this option and provided Admin user and password. Still the error is same. Please find the attached screenshot.

Comment: Go to Sevices. Properties there would be a tab called Log on in there specifiy the username and password and restart the service.

Comment: Thank you for making me understand. As of now I couldn't see any service related to Jenkins in my services. 

FYI, I am trying to make a Windows 7 VM as jenkins slave for the first time. My jenkins master is running on CentOS 7.4

Comment: I could able to fix this "Service Logon Failure" issue by following below steps:

The user that is used for logging on also needs the permission "Log on as a service":

To open Local Security Policy, click Start, point to Control Panel, point to Administrative Tools, and then double-click Local Security Policy.
In the console tree, double-click Local Policies, and then click User Rights Assignment.
In the details pane, double-click Log on as a service.
 Click Add User or Group, and then add the appropriate account to the list of accounts that possess the Log on as a service right.

Comment: I had the same issue on a Windows 7 slave with a Jenkins 2.190.1 Jenkins master, and the comment above resolved it.This was done after all the steps listed [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slaves-plugin/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.adoc).